# Do I need to reconnect every 15 minutes with RDS IAM authentication

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using RDS postgresql with IAM authentication. In my application, it generates the token at runtime before it connects to RDS cluster. Based on AWS document,

`An authentication token is a string of characters that you use instead of a password. After you generate an authentication token, it's valid for 15 minutes before it expires. If you try to connect using an expired token, the connection request is denied.`,

the token is only valid for 15 minutes. My question is that do I need to reconnect every 15 minutes? If the connection is already set up, does it require token for each query/insert/update etc.? If it doesn't require the token, that means I need to keep my connection always open. Does RDS support that connection mode?

Comment: This may assist you: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> My question is that do I need to reconnect every 15 minutes?

No you don't. The token is required to establish connection, and does not determine how long the existing connection can last for. The default value for connection to be alive without activity is 28800s (8 hours) as explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-3-parameters-related-to-security-operational-manageability-and-connectivity-timeout/).

This means that if you terminate your connection, or mysql terminates it due to not being actively used, then you need to get a new token to re-connect if the existing one already expired.

Comment: The topic starter was referring to PostgreSQL and the referenced link is about MySQL.

Comment: Yes. This is not Aurora postgres in the link. I think if we establish a connection , after around 14 minutes there is an issue manifesting as I/O exception.

Answer (score 2):

If your connection to the DB is interrupted (for any number of reasons) and you need to re-connect and it is greater than 15 minutes since you created the token you will need to create a new token. Otherwise if you maintain a connection to the DB your access will not be interrupted after successfully authenticating.

[From AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.html) "The token is only used for authentication and doesn't affect the session after it is established."

There is no way to increase the Token lifespan for greater than 15 minutes. [This Github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues/63#issuecomment-438050396) shows where others have encountered the same issue, when using IAM for RDS via the short lived Tokens.

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.html) for connecting to RDS via IAM role/user.

[Recommendations from AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.ConnectionsPerSecond) suggest to "use IAM database authentication as a mechanism for temporary, personal access to databases."

Comment: "use IAM database authentication as a mechanism for temporary..." I couldn't find this in the link you provided. Is this still the case? I'm trying to put IAM auth to a serverless application and just wanted to make sure I'm heading in the right direction.